# Python library for Tibco message queue connection with client and server side python scripting

Tags: python, message-queue, tibco, tibco-ems, tibco-rv

Need a proper python library for Tibco message queue - client side and server side samples as well in python.

**On Client side programing using python program: Below are the action items**

1. Required to connect Tibco message queue.
2. Send the user request to Tibco.

**On Server side programing using python program: Below are the action items**

1. Required to connect Tibco message queue.
2. Process the request generated by the client side.
3. Respond back the result to client.

Need Tibco specific python library and also the generic messaging queue python library (which is adaptable to Tibco as well as Kafka).

Comment: Are you talking about Kafka or TIBCO EMS ? It would be useful to clarify this

Comment: For Python support by EMS you may have a look to the following TIBCO KB article :
https://support.tibco.com/s/article/Tibco-KnowledgeArticle-Article-40747

Comment: Need a python library to connect the message queue. Both client side scripting  (to send the request to message queue) and server side scripting (to process the request sent by the client) as well.

(1) Instead of kafka or Tibco  - I need a generic Python API to connect to message queue to achieve both client side and server side scripting. i.e. Message queue may be either Tibco EMS to kafka. 

(2) If #1 is not possible i.e. If Python does not have generic module for Message queue mechanism. Share the standard python API for connecting both Tibco and Kafka message queue.

Comment: There is no official Python API for EMS, meanwhile you may have a look to open source solutions like this one :  https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyems/